# How to implement a table to know the default object of an application in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

For example I have this tables:

1. USERS.
2. OBJECTS.
3. MY_OBJECTS.

As you know MY_OBJECTS links USERS with OBJECTS tables.

MY_OBJECTS structure:

```
(code, object_code, user_code)
```

If I want to know the default object defined by the user or the application I need to put a new field in the table MY_OBJECTS like:

```
(code, object_code, user_code, default_object)
```

**default_object** field could be an INT, that indicates if the object is default or not (0 not default, 1 default), BUT, I cannot define multiple objects as default, and the table is allowing that:

```
(1,1,3,0)
(2,2,3,0)
(3,3,3,1) -->default object
(4,3,3,1) -->default object !!!
(5,3,3,1) -->default object !!!
(6,6,3,0)
(7,6,3,1) -->default object !!!
(8,6,3,1) -->default object !!!
(9,6,3,0)
```

What I want, is to found a way for define default objects BUT not multiple default objects. The solution by the moment is set to 0 the **default_object** field for all objects, each time a object will defined as default, also this isn't defined as database structure (programming solution). Well, may be youk now a database structure solution for this.

Look what I want for people that is understanding problem (compare the above rows):

```
(1,1,3,0)
(2,2,3,0)
(3,3,3,1) -->default object
(4,3,3,0) 
(5,3,3,0) 
(6,6,3,0)
(7,6,3,1) -->default object !!!
(8,6,3,0) 
(9,6,3,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you can just add a "default object" field to your USERS table. That would allow a 1:1 between users and objects for the default case, while still allowing 1:n for users:objects in general.

Comment: this is well, but the user will has multiple objects, I can't define multiple default objects in one field

Comment: You said you didn't want multiple defaults: "BUT, I cannot define multiple objects as default,".

Comment: cannot define multiple default objects of the same type (same code)

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the default object attribute in the `users` table?

Comment: this is well, but the user will has multiple objects, I can't define multiple default objects in one field

Comment: You'll still have your `my_objects` table for One user to many objects association.

Comment: The attribute for default object in user table is 1 user to 1 default object. Hence you will have two associations instead of one.

#1 - One user has many objects (using my_objects table) and
#2 - One user has one default object (using default_object attribute in User table)